# How to add images to pdf with template and concat of pages

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, itext

I'm struggling to insert images on a multi-page PDF.
To create several pages I'm using PdfConcatenate, and it works. I get to add pages of my template perfectly. The problem starts when I try to add images. It just doesn't load them.

Here's the code that works to add images:

```
        string pdfTemplate = @"Tools\template.pdf";
        string targetPdfPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), fileName + ".pdf");

        FileStream output = new FileStream(targetPdfPath, FileMode.Create);
        PdfConcatenate pdfConcatenate = new PdfConcatenate(output);

        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
        MemoryStream memoryStream = getMemoryStream(output);
        PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, output);

        int cardIndex = 1;

        foreach (Registry reg in registries)
        {
            setFields(reg, pdfStamper, cardIndex);

            if (cardIndex == 4)
            {
                pdfConcatenate.AddPages(pdfReader);
                pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
                pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, output);

                cardIndex = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                cardIndex++;
            }
        }

        //if (cardIndex != 1)
        //    pdfConcatenate.AddPages(pdfReader);

        //make the form no longer editable
        pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;

        pdfStamper.Close();
        pdfReader.Close();
        //pdfConcatenate.Close();
```

If use MemoryStream for PdfStamper and uncomment these lines:

```
//if (cardIndex != 1)
//    pdfConcatenate.AddPages(pdfReader);
//pdfConcatenate.Close();
```

I get it to add pages, but without images.

Any idea of what is wrong?

> **SOLUTION: (Thanks to @mkl)**

```
        string pdfTemplate = @"Tools\template.pdf";
        string targetPdfPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), fileName + ".pdf");

        FileStream output = new FileStream(targetPdfPath, FileMode.Create);
        PdfConcatenate pdfConcatenate = new PdfConcatenate(output);

        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, memoryStream);

        int cardIndex = 1;

        foreach (Registry reg in registries)
        {
            setFields(reg, pdfStamper, cardIndex);

            if (cardIndex == 4)
            {
                pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
                pdfStamper.Close();
                PdfReader tempReader = new PdfReader(memoryStream.ToArray());

                pdfConcatenate.AddPages(tempReader);

                memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
                pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, memoryStream);

                cardIndex = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                cardIndex++;
            }
        }

        if (cardIndex != 1)
        {
            pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
            pdfStamper.Close();
            PdfReader tempReader = new PdfReader(memoryStream.ToArray());

            pdfConcatenate.AddPages(tempReader);

            tempReader.Close();
        }

        pdfStamper.Close();
        pdfReader.Close();
        pdfConcatenate.Close();
```

Comment: You have the PdfConcatenate and an unknown number of PdfStamper instances all writing the same file. If you are lucky, one of then wins. Otherwise you either get some exception or garbage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem most likely is some misconception on how `PdfStamper`works. You seem to think it somehow manipulates the data in the `PdfReader` it stamps, and also pages exported from that reader beforehand. This is **not** the case, a `PdfStamper` generates a new PDF file (in its output stream) based on the data in the reader but the contents of the reader itself are not updated to also reflect all the changes (the `PdfReader` object may be touched in the process, though, and not be reusable afterwards). So...

As already mentioned in the comment, you have the `PdfConcatenate` and an unknown number of `PdfStamper` instances all writing the same `FileStream' output. As each of these objects creates an independant PDF, you are lucky if one of then wins because then you'll get at least a proper PDF as output. Otherwise you either get some exception or garbage consisting of multiple intermingled PDFs. Thus, make only PdfConcatenate target your output file.

If your actual intent is to repeatedly fill the template fields with the content of 4 cards each time and combine the results, you should **not** add the pages from the `PdfReader` of the template to the `PdfConcatenate` --- the pages in that reader are not filled in! --- but instead have the PdfStamper output to a `MemoryStream`, fill its fields, flatten its form, close it, open its output in a new `PdfReader`, and add all the pages in that reader to the PdfConcatenate.

I don't dare to put that into code as I'm predominantly using Java and writing down untested C# code most likely would include multiple errors... ;)

PS: Currently you count on all the `PdfReader` instances you open to be implicitly closed somewhere. While that is true currently, recent check-ins in the iText SVN repository seem to indicate that these implicit close calls are removed from the code. Thus, please also start explicitly closing `PdfReader` instances you dont't use anymore. Otherwise you will soon have to deal with memory leaks due to readers closing much too late..

Comment: I upvoted this answer and I want the code removed from the question or I'll downvote it because I don't want other people to read this and copy code that is all wrong; eestein should read this first: http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really want to repeatedly fill the template each time and merge the results. I have a PDF Form that I'm using as a template, but the generated PDF might contain several pages, not only one. And there's where I was having trouble. I look into your approach right now and come back with the result. Thanks again.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thanks for the link to your book sample, I'll look into that. About the code in the question, it's a question, not an answer, it shouldn't be view as correct.

Comment: I know, but nevertheless: plenty of people just copy/paste code without reading the context. Also, you said "Here's the code that works to add images". In any case: I see that the question was updated. Thank you!